# Can't fix NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to get data for a Country spinner from internet using AsynTask. I got the NoClassDefFoundError, I checked, the common-io-2.5.jar was in the classpath. I'm using Eclipse. The code crashes when the Type token is declared.
I don't know how to fix this, please help me. Thank you very much!

```
package fantasticmassage.com;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator; 

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.renderscript.Type;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class CountrySpinner extends Activity{
    private Spinner spnCountry;
    private ArrayList<Country> countries;
    private ArrayAdapter<Country> spnCountryAdapter; 

    public CountrySpinner(){

    }
    public CountrySpinner(Spinner spn){
        this.spnCountry = spn;
    }
    public CountrySpinner(Spinner spn, ArrayAdapter<Country> adapter){
        this.spnCountry = spn;
        this.spnCountryAdapter = adapter;
    }

    public void getDataForCountrySpinner(){
        new CountrySpinnerAsync().execute();
    }
    public class CountrySpinnerAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override 
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            System.out.println("onPreExecute: passed");
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://leansigmaway.com/api/ca_api/api.php?type=getCountries");
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.connect();
                String result = IOUtils.toString(httpURLConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                String countryList = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result").toString();
                Type token = (Type) new TypeToken<ArrayList<Country>>(){}.getType();//Look like it crashes right here
                System.out.println("doInBacground, token: " + token);

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                countries = gson.fromJson(countryList, (java.lang.reflect.Type) token);

                spnCountryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Country>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, countries);
                spnCountryAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid){
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            spnCountry.setAdapter(spnCountryAdapter);
        }
    }

    private class Country implements Comparator<Country> {

        @SerializedName("id")
        private int countryID;

        @SerializedName("name")
        private String countryName;

        public Country() {
        }

        public Country(int countryID, String countryName) {
            this.countryID = countryID;
            this.countryName = countryName;
        }

        public int getCountryID() {
            return countryID;
        }

        public void setCountryID(int countryID) {
            this.countryID = countryID;
        }

        public String getCountryName() {
            return countryName;
        }

        public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
            this.countryName = countryName;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return countryName;
        }


        @Override
        public int compare(Country lhs, Country rhs) {
            return lhs.getCountryName().compareTo(rhs.getCountryName());
        }
    }

}
```

And the log file:

```
07-21 22:00:59.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1948): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-21 22:00:59.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1948): Process: fantasticmassage.com, PID: 1948
07-21 22:00:59.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1948): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-21 22:00:59.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1948):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
07-21 22:00:59.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1948):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
07-21 22:00:59.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1948):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
07-21 22:00:59.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1948):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
07-21 22:00:59.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1948):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-21 22:00:59.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1948):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-21 22:00:59.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1948):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-21 22:00:59.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1948):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-21 22:00:59.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1948): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fantasticmassage.com.CountrySpinner$CountrySpinnerAsync$1
07-21 22:00:59.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1948):     at fantasticmassage.com.CountrySpinner$CountrySpinnerAsync.doInBackground(CountrySpinner.java:74)
07-21 22:00:59.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1948):     at fantasticmassage.com.CountrySpinner$CountrySpinnerAsync.doInBackground(CountrySpinner.java:1)
07-21 22:00:59.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1948):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-21 22:00:59.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1948):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-21 22:00:59.378: E/AndroidRuntime(1948):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: I think scope is the issue, so change private class Country to public class Country

Comment: did you tried my solution??

Comment: you have not included lifecycle methods(like oncreate,onResume) in your activity

Comment: I tried you solution and it works like I said below, thank you Sathish.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

`Clean your project` and `rebuild` it again.. most of the issues like `NoClassDefFoundError` will solve like this.

Comment: @M.N then you can approve this answer as the correct one

Comment: Ajay, I did, thanks! I didn't see the stick icon, I'm new to stackoverflow too.

Answer (score 0):

From official documentation, this exception is thrown because of

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be found.

So I think you are giving wrong path for your class definition in your first line of code. Try giving correct path after package keyword and your problem will be solved. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my case of `NoClassDefFoundError` error i did following method. that's work for me.

Go `Project Name Right Click -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export -> common-io-2.5.jar (Check this jar)`

after that `Click common-io-2.5.jar -> Click Up (in right side panel) -> Ok`

This may solve your problem.

Comment: I fail to see how the commons io project helps solve the problem in the question

Comment: Sure, but it sounds like you fixed a class that was missing in the Commons IO, which is not what the question is missing.

Comment: It works for me Sathish, thank you very much, no NoClassDefFoundError anymore although I encountered another issue (as always :-)). How can I increase a point for this answer when my point is still too low?

Comment: Hi Sathish, it suddenly doesn't work today, the same error. I tried to clean the project, not working, could you please take a further look?

Comment: check your `.jar` file found in same location or not

Comment: It is at the same location. I'm the only one who is working on this on my own computer.